Referencing WPF project from non-WPF project in .NET 8
Update 11.11.24: OK, so it was a little late when I had the issue come up and I mixed things up. I corrected my question and updated the title. I hope that the issue is now a little more clear.
So here are the csproj files for the projects in question. As long as I only reference "Modules.DataAnalysis" in "Modules.DataAnalysis.Tests", everything is fine, but for easier setup I tried to reference "Modules.UI", and that's when everything went south. I can do it without referencing "Modules.UI" in the unit test project by just mocking the return value I get from the UI (the interface for calling the UI and the return value are both in Modules.DataAnalysis anyway, but it was late and I wanted to take a shortcut for some quick tests), but I was surprised that it didn't work, and I wanted to understand why. Is it not possible to reference a WPF project from a non-WPF project?
Modules.DataAnalysis.Tests:

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\src\modules\Modules.DataAnalysis\Modules.DataAnalysis.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.20.72" />
  <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.9.2" />
</ItemGroup>

Modules.DataAnalysis:

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <InternalsVisibleTo Include="Modules.DataAnalysis.Tests" />
</ItemGroup>

Modules.UI:

<PropertyGroup>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Page Update="Views\EntryConfirmationView.xaml">
    <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  </Page>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="8.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Prism.Wpf" Version="8.1.97" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Common\Common.csproj" />
  <ProjectReference Include="..\Modules.DataAnalysis\Modules.DataAnalysis.csproj" />
  <ProjectReference Include="..\Modules.IO\Modules.IO.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <InternalsVisibleTo Include="Modules.DataAnalysis.Tests" />
</ItemGroup>

All projects are: Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"
Error message:
Modules.DataAnalysis.Tests.csproj: [NU1201] Project Modules.UI is not compatible with net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0). Project Modules.UI supports: net8.0-windows7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)
The weirdest part is that the usings to Moq are not found once I reference Modules.UI.
Original question, which was nonsense:
I'm currently upgrading the projects of one of my hobby programs from .Net Framework 4.7.2 to .NET 8. The project containing UI stuff is a .NET 8 WPF project. The other projects which are just class libraries without any UI related stuff I set up as .NET 8 projects, but now I get error messages when the WPF project tries to reference the non-WPF projects.
The error message I get is
Error NU1201 : Project ABC is not compatible with net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0). Project ABC supports: net8.0-windows7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)
What am I doing wrong?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If you create a new wpf project and a class library, you will find it works. Which means we're guessing what you have and what you did.
